# Knowing in a Section if another Section has already been executed

Tags: nsis

I want to create a Suite installer for the various application we develop. The structure is as follows:

- Application A
  Requires no driver installation
- Application B
  Requires driver 1 and 2
- Application C
  Requires driver 2 and 3

The user has the option to install any application he wants, or multiple. I know how to use Sections for this. This will work fine if the user selects only Application A, or Application A with either B or C. However, if the user selects Application B and C, I would like to avoid that driver 2 will be prompted to install twice.

Is there a way to achieve this? For instance, is it possible to know when the section for Application C is executed, that the section for Application B has already been executed, and that driver 2 does not need to be installed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to handle this, one is to put the driver in a hidden section that you make sure is in the correct state:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Sections.nsh
!include x64.nsh

Page Components
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

Section "-Driver2" SID_DRIVER2
${If} ${IsNativeAMD64}
    ; Install AMD64 64-bit driver/library
${ElseIf} ${IsNativeARM64}
    ; Install ARM64 64-bit driver/library
${ElseIf} ${IsNativeIA32}
    ; Install i386 32-bit driver/library
${Else}
    Abort "Unsupported CPU architecture!"
${EndIf}
SectionEnd

Section "App B" SID_APPB
SectionEnd

Section /o "App C" SID_APPC
SectionEnd

Function .onSelChange
${If} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_APPB}
${OrIf} ${SectionIsSelected} ${SID_APPC}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_DRIVER2}
${Else}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_DRIVER2}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function .onInit
Call .onSelChange ; Make sure things are configured correctly in silent installers
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks! Two things that were not yet in my NSIS scripting portfolio: if/then/else conditions in sections, and .onSelChange. This will help me forward.